# Device is Registered for notification but did not get device token

Tags: objective-c

here my code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    {

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes: (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound) categories:nil]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }

    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];

       return YES;

}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    //register to receive notifications
    NSLog(@"device registered...");
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];

}
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    //    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
    NSString *deviceID = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    deviceID = [deviceID stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
      str_DeviceToken = deviceID;
    NSLog(@"device token is %@",str_DeviceToken);
}
```

I neither get any device token error nor get device token when i run this code into device.

I spent  a day behind find the issue  please help to get device token.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You really should not check the OS version just use: `if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])`

Comment: Are you testing it on Simulator? if YES Push Notification doesn't work on Simulator, Use Real device to test it. If you are using Real device then make sure it Prompts for Push Notification Permission, if it doesn't check your device settings.

Comment: Dipen Panchasara, I am testing on real device and it  prompts push notification permission

Comment: @Hetal Actually, I have test your code and its working fine with my demo project and it generates the device token. I think you should check your APNS certificate.

Comment: `- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error{}` add this delegate method of `UIApplicationDelegate` and check its called or not!!